# CNAMES between two domains

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl, cname-record

This is a two part question

**PART 1**

I have two domains

1. domain1.com, with a subdomain (sub1.sub2.domain1.com)
2. domain2.com, with no subdomains.

If I create a CNAME of corp.domain2.com, that points to sub1.sub2.domain1.com

Will that work? or do I need to configure anything from the domain1.com side of things?

**PART 2**

if sub1.sub2.domain1.com is secured with a wildcard SSL, and someone visits corp.domain2.com which is just a cname for sub1.sub2.domain1.com, will the browser invoke a SSL security warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Part 1:** Yes. A CNAME is just one record, and it is only configured in one place. It doesn't even have to point to a valid name, but you will then get an error when you try to resolve it.

**Part 2:** If you open a browser to `corp.domain2.com` and the certificate says that the name is supposed to be `*.domain1.com`, then **yes**, you will get a warning.

You could configure a redirect on your web server to tell everyone coming to `corp.domain2.com`, that they should visit `sub1.sub2.domain1.com` instead. But this will only work if they open `http://corp.domain2.com/`. You will still see a warning if you open the SSL version at `https://corp.domain2.com/` though.

Comment: Is there any way to get the name of the original host.

For example if you went to http://corp.domain2.com, and it's really a name for sub1.sub2.domain1.com, how can I get the corp.domain2.com string using php? Would it be a $_SERVER variable?

Comment: Test it out, @mrc0der. Look at the output of `phpinfo()` for the name. But yes, you are right. It will be the `_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]` variable. Also check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297403/http-host-vs-server-name

Comment: I have another issue now: 

I have a sub2.sub1.domain1.com that's a CNAME that points to sub1.domain1.com; I also have a sub3.domain2.com that is a CNAME that points to sub2.sub1.domain1.com; Now though sub2.sub1.domain1.com works fine and shows the content from sub1.domain1.com, but when i go to sub3.domain2.com it shows the content for domain1.com only, now the subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

**Part 1**

Yes, it will work.

In domain1.com dns, you need something like follow

```
    sub1.sub2    IN A     "some IP address"
```

or

```
    sub1.sub2    IN CNAME "some hostname"
```

Then in domain2.com, you add the CNAME

```
    corp         IN CNAME sub1.sub2.domain1.com.
```

**Part 2**

There should be no warning, as SSL is IP base. Following link actually answer in details

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935229/cname-ssl-certificates